# How to disable cookies in Chrome using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to disable cookies at the beginning of my test. I tried using options but it does not work.
Now i am using

```
WebDriver driver = getDriver();
driver.get("chrome://settings/content/cookies");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("labelWrapper"));
```

but still cannot select any of the options. I receive an error that the element does not exist, but when i use Developer tools i can see that it is there.

I am using

- testCompile group: "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name: "selenium-java", version: "3.141.59"
- testCompile group: "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name: "selenium-chrome-driver", version: "3.141.59"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is working for me :

```
driver.get("chrome://settings/content/cookies");
WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.tagName("settings-ui"));
WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=container"));
WebElement main = root2.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=main"));
WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(main);
WebElement shadowRoot4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(getByIdentifier("class=showing-subpage"));
WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot4);
WebElement shadowRoot6 = shadowRoot5.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=advancedPage"));
WebElement shadowRoot7 = shadowRoot6.findElement(By.tagName("settings-privacy-page"));
WebElement shadowRoot8 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot7);
WebElement shadowRoot9 = shadowRoot8.findElement(getByIdentifier("id=pages"));
WebElement shadowRoot10 = shadowRoot9.findElement(By.tagName("settings-subpage"));
WebElement shadowRoot11 = shadowRoot10.findElement(By.tagName("category-default-setting"));
WebElement shadowRoot12 = expandRootElement(shadowRoot11);
WebElement shadowRoot13 = shadowRoot12.findElement(By.id("toggle"));
shadowRoot13.click();
```

Comment: @DebanjanB I found solution. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

### First the solution

To disable cookies on recent *Chrome* browsers you need to `setPreference()` the attribute **`network.cookie.cookieBehavior`** as follows:

- Chrome:

  ```
  prefs.put("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2);
  ```
- Firefox:

  ```
  profile.setPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2);
  ```

---

### History

To disable the cookies in *Chrome Browsing Context* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use a `Map` object to configure `default_content_setting_values` of **cookies** as **`2`** as follows:

```
put("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 2);
```

Effectively, your code block will be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 2);
prefs.put("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 2);
prefs.put("profile.block_third_party_cookies", True);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I tried that but when i start the test and check, all the cookies are available

Comment: @BozhidarMarinov Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: The same behaviour. Cookies are not disabled.

Comment: @BozhidarMarinov Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.